# laravel where multiple input array

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-8

i have an array like this :

```
array:2 [▼
0 => 1
1 => 2
]
```

and i have product table like this :

```
"id" => 1
    "nama" => "product1"
    "harga" => 100000
    "created_at" => "2021-05-01 15:21:08"
    "updated_at" => "2021-05-01 15:21:08"
  ]
"id" => 2
    "nama" => "product2"
    "harga" => 90000
    "created_at" => "2021-05-01 15:21:08"
    "updated_at" => "2021-05-01 15:21:08"
  ]
"id" => 3
    "nama" => "product3"
    "harga" => 80000
    "created_at" => "2021-05-01 15:21:08"
    "updated_at" => "2021-05-01 15:21:08"
  ]
 
 and more ...
```

i want to find product data using `where` id with multiple input, example :

```
array:2 [▼
0 => 1
1 => 2
]

the result : 

"id" => 1
"nama" => "product1"
"harga" => 100000
"created_at" => "2021-05-01 15:21:08"
"updated_at" => "2021-05-01 15:21:08"
]
 "id" => 2
 "nama" => "product2"
 "harga" => 90000
 "created_at" => "2021-05-01 15:21:08"
 "updated_at" => "2021-05-01 15:21:08"
 ]
```

is it possible? very happy when someone hepl and tell me how, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use whereIn from Query Builder. see [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)

```
$users = DB::table('users')
             ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
             ->get();
```